# Multi login using Facebook, Twitter, and internal login issue

Tags: facebook, web-applications, twitter, authentication

I am creating an app in which you can login via [Facebook](http://Facebook), [Twitter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twitter), or our own internal mechanism. The issue is the following scenario:

1. I open the app and login using Facebook
2. I logout
3. I open the app and login using Twitter

The above scenario will result in me as a user having two accounts in the system. How do I prevent this from happening so that I have one account and it doesn't matter whether I login using Facebook/Twitter?

Every time a user login using Facebook I am as well creating an internal account, with the Facebook username and Facebook id as password. The same thing when I login using Twitter I am creating an internal account with the Twitter user name and id as password.

An idea came in my mind to solve this:

When a user logs in using Twitter check the name and email if a user with that information already exists in the database. However, the name and email they use in both Facebook and Twitter might not be the same, so this might not work all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't make this work with your current flow (when the user logs in then logs out again). Instead you should allow a user to login with either their Facebook or Twitter credentials and then, **whilst they're still logged in**, get them to associate their account with their other service with that user.

So, the flow would be something like:

1. New user arrives at site User logs in with Facebooks oauth2
   mechanism
2. Your server receives their FB ID and generates a new user
   in your systems. Stores their FB ID against that user.
3. You prompt
   the user to add their twitter auth credentials. User logs in with
   Twitter oauth2 mechanism
4. Your server receives their twitter ID,
   checks to see if a user is currently logged in with your
   application. Because there is, you save the twitter ID agains the
   current user.

Later, the user can log out and then log in with either service.

Comment: what if they want to sign in using the internal account?

Comment: and what if they don't associate their twitter account while they log in, and they log out and decide "hey I want to login using my twitter account"

Comment: Nowhere in your (or my) flow did we talk about your users having a username/password for your service separate from the facebook/twitter logins. If you want that you should add it as another 'credential authority' in the same way that you're adding facebook/twitter

Comment: your second question is much harder to enforce, but generally people are smart enough to remember which service they used to sign up to various other websites. If they've signed in with Facebook they're unlikely to go 'oh, I'll sign in with twitter and the website will just know who I am'. That's bullshit. No other site works like that. Just make it easy for people to see their account details and encourage them to add facebook/twitter integration early. It's all about leading the user to do what you want them to do

Comment: ok, so in the end if say an outliar user decided to do that stuff I mentioned, he/she will have two accounts and it is not my responsibility to handle that as long as I have already redirect that person to connect him/her to the social network first place?

Comment: in the same way that if someone first initially signed in using the internal username/password then he logs out and signs in again using twitter, this will be a new account

Comment: Correct. You could of course provide a 'merge account' feature. So, user signs in with username/password having signed up already with twitter. Then tries to add their existing twitter account to the account they're signed in with.

You'd have to kill off the old (twitter authed) account and add the auth to their current account. Without knowing your application in details it's impossible to tell you how hard/sensible this approach would be

Comment: Yea, that's what I was planning to do.. thanks for all the insights

Comment: I'm facing the same issue here, I think What you do is offer to merge the account once one is logged-in and if he does not, you keep this merging possibility in the my profile section. If the user try to add the other network to the account he's logged in then you merge the two if another one exist.